# STM32 - Fastest way to change ADC channels after each conversion

Tags: adc, stm32, brushless-dc-motor, firmware

I'm using the STSPIN32F0 (**edit: I'm using the STPIN32F0 6-step control evaluation board from ST called STEVAL-SPIN3202**) to develop a 6-step speed controller for brushless DC motors. The STSPIN has an integrated STM32F031C6 microcontroller. I've set up my system to trigger ADC conversions on TIM1 update events, where TIM1 is configured as a center-aligned waveform.

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do. On the PWM off-time, I want to sample an ADC channel corresponding to the phase on which BEMF is being measured for the current step. On the PWM on-time, I want to sample an ADC channel corresponding to the current sense network.

[image]

The BEMF reads must correspond to the TIM1 update events that happen on the counter up->down transition, and the current reads must happen on the TIM1 update events that happen on the counter down->up transition.

To achieve this synchronization, I decided to structure my firmware so that on each ADC conversion, the conversion-complete callback toggles the ADC channel.

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{ 
   /* This is called after the conversion is completed */ 
   if(__HAL_TIM_IS_TIM_COUNTING_DOWN(&htim1))
   { 
      //read bemf 
      SM_sampleBEMF(); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      //read current 
      SM_sampleCurrent(); 
   }
}

void SM_sampleBEMF() 
{ 
   bemf = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc); 
   if(bemf < BEMF_thresh)
   { 
      HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim2, __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2) << 1); 
   } 
   num_bemfs++; 
   ADC_Channel(ADC_CURRENT_CHANNEL); 
} 

void SM_sampleCurrent() 
{ 
   current_error = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc) - current_reference; 
   current_error_acc += current_error; 
   num_currents++; 
   ADC_Channel(currentBemfAdcChannel); 
}

inline void ADC_Channel(uint32_t adc_ch) 
{ 
   hadc.Instance->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTP; 
   while(hadc.Instance->CR & ADC_CR_ADSTP); 
   hadc.Instance->CHSELR = ADC_CHSELR_CHANNEL(adc_ch); 
   hadc.Instance->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART; 
}
```

I'm observing is that the entire cycle of converting a channel, processing the conversion complete callback, and changing the ADC channel does not happen quickly enough. I'm running TIM1 at 30 kHz, which means the update events happen at 60kHz. Wondering if there's a way to speed up the ADC Channel toggling compared to how I've implemented it? Or is my only option to slow down the PWM frequency.

The BEMF data must be processed at as high a speed as possible because the controller needs to detect BEMF zero-crossing. I decided therefore that slowing the update event generation or buffering multiple ADC reads with some sort of DMA setup was not an option.

Appreciate any suggestions on alternate approaches to my goal as well.

Comment: Did you write your own ADC code or are you using libraries? If using libraries, write your own so you actually know what it's doing. I would not have tried to measure 30kHz zero-crossing with just one multiplexed ADC. Actually, if I wasn't sure I could do it, I would have built in a hardware comparator zero-crossing circuit, just in case I needed it. Then in the future I would have a better idea of if I actually needed it or not.

Comment: @DKNguyen the ADC switching code is provided at the bottom, called void ADC_Channel. The implementation here is just with adc register operations

Comment: I'm trying to sense for zero-crossing at 30kHz. Also, I'm using an eval board for the STSPIN32F0 IC, so i'm limited in the available hardware (it doesn't have a zero-crossing detector).

Comment: If you think the mux switching code is the problem and not the mux itself (I couldn't find switching information in the datasheet) you could try triggering to scan all three phases as a sequence off the timer and just use the channel value you want. If it really is 1Msps, it should be fast enough to grab all three phases within your time span.

Comment: I've only ever used scan mode for STM32 ADC. @DKNguyen 's suggestion of using timer injection+scan mode is exactly the technique I used for a hybrid trapezoidal+foc controller. I think you're wrong to rule out using the DMA, I don't follow your logic there

Comment: Oh, and use the timer to directly trigger the ADC sample. Not trigger an timer interrupt which then runs code to grab an ADC sample (you were sampling the ADC through a timer interrupt which you may have been forced to do if the ADC channel change had to be done in software, but now you don't need to)

Comment: You have two options, I think. One - as @DKNguyen suggested configure continuous circular DMA reading of all your channels (which will not use ANY controller cycles at all), and two - use triggers to initiate conversion only when necessary, and reconfigure ADC to next channel when you done, so next conversion can be started quickly